# Get data from url in php

Tags: php, get

Is it possible to put this:

```
<?php echo $_GET['p']; ?>
```

Inside of this:

```
<?php include("vars.txt"); 
echo"".$title.""; ?>
```

Actually I want to get the filename? (example: vars.txt) from URL. Can anyone tell me how to do this?

Comment: Found this when searching on google, what you should have done: http://www.phpeasystep.com/phptu/27.html Is that what you need ? SO is not Google, there are plenty and plenty of tutorials about GET on the internet

Comment: Why my codes are not showing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a $url

`$url = "http://example.com/file/vars.txt";`

and want to display on-screen text "Filename: vars.txt" then you can use the code below to do that

```
$filename = basename($url);
echo "Filename $filename";
```

Edited Answer:

What you are trying to do is potentially quite dangerous as anyone can select any file from your server to include in your page and get your website hacked, to make this a bit more secure you can do the following

```
<?php
$files = array(
   "vars" => "vars.txt",
   "vars2" => "vars2.txt",
   "some-other-file" => "vars3.txt"
); 

if( $_GET['p'] && isset( $files[ $_GET['p'] ] ) {
    echo file_get_contents( $files[ $_GET['p'] ] );
}
?>
```

Then when you enter an URL like http://example.com/?p=vars then vars.txt content will be print on the screen.

Comment: Can u send me full script? I'm new at php. Thanks

Comment: I would need some more details to help you, can you let me know from where do you get the URL (in my example "http://example.com/file/vars.txt")?

Comment: I want to get the filename from url and want to use that file at include('file.txt'). Url will be http://example.com/index.php?p=file

Comment: I want to get the filename from url and want to use that file at include('file.txt') isntead of file.txt. Url will be http://example.com/index.php?p=vars. So the php code will show include('vars.txt'). Thanks

Comment: Thanks sir. It's working better. And thanks for your answer with secured script. Thanks a lot. 

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can put it in there.
Here is the code:

```
<phpinclude($_GET[“p”]);
echo “”.$title.””; ?>
```

The url will look like example.com/file?p=vars.txt

Comment: Thanks sir, it's working. 